# how to count with database statement by using netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans

I'm trying to count the input and match it with the data field in database then count the status and display the number of books that the input had borrowed.

```
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(jtfMemberID.getText()) as num FROM LOAN WHERE LOAN_STATUS='BORROWED'";

        ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(sql); 
        int personCount = 0; 

        if(rs1.next()) { 
            personCount = rs1.getInt("num");
            jlbBookBorrow.setText(rs1.getString(personCount));
        }else{
            jlbBookBorrow.setText("0");
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The text `jtfMemberID.getText()` will be interpreted literally in your `SQL` `String`. You need to extract it out:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(" + jtfMemberID.getText() + ") as num FROM LOAN WHERE LOAN_STATUS='BORROWED'";
```

Also, to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, consider using [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).